# Table Name Mapping not working in EF 6 when using POCO classes

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-6

I am using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.TableAttribute in class below, so class 'Order_Details' is mapped to table 'Order Details' in Northwind database.

There is an attribute [Table("Order Details"] just above class definition to map it to a database table.

The problem is when a LINQ query executes against the database, it tries to query 'Order_Details' table in the database, when it should be querying 'Order Details' table.

**Question**: Do I have to use some other attribute for mapping this class to 'Order Details' table in the database? This POCO class ( without the table attribute) was generated by a third-party code generator using Entity Framework.

```
[Table("Order Details")]
public class Order_Details
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Order I D")]
    public Int32 OrderID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Product I D")]
    public Int32 ProductID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Unit Price")]
    public Decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Quantity")]
    public Int16 Quantity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Discount")]
    public Decimal Discount { get; set; }

    // ComboBox
    public virtual Orders Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual Products Products { get; set; }

}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Since there was no edmx file and it was using  'Code first fluent API' as suggested by Jeow Li Huan in his answer, I add a table mapping for 'Order Details' in modelcreating event and it worked then.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            //added this in place of Table attribute and it works
            modelBuilder.Entity<Order_Details>().ToTable("Order Details");

            modelBuilder.Entity<Orders>().ToTable("Orders");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Products>().ToTable("Products");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customers>().ToTable("Customers");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Employees>().ToTable("Employees");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Shippers>().ToTable("Shippers");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Suppliers>().ToTable("Suppliers");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Categories>().ToTable("Categories");

        }
```

**UPDATE 2**:

Also, another solution as suggested by Jeow, was to remove the model creating event and just use the original table attribute. This also worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code first fluent API**

Did the tool you use also generated a `DbContext` with `OnModelCreating` method that uses code to map your `Order_Details` to `Order_Details` table?

If there is, remove it.

**Database/model first**

Did the tool you use generate .edmx file that causes all the attributes on the class to be ignored? (Check under your connection string for `metadata=res://*/Models.Model.csdl`, which implies that .edmx is being used).

If there is .edmx, then you'll have to map the table using that file.

**I think the old code first works this way**

Did the tool store the edmx schema in the database? Look for tables you did not create in your database.

If there is edmx schema in the db, you'll have to modify that.

Comment: Yes,  there is a method called OnModelCreating in code generated, but there is no edmx file and no connection string like you mentioned. There is also no edmx schema. So I think the tool is using Code first fluent API. I will try your suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: I added a table mapping in model creating event and then it worked. I removed the table attribute mapping from the 'Order_Details' class. You can look at my code under UPDATE 1 for this change.

Comment: I followed your advice by removing the  model creating event code and instead used my original table attribute and it worked. That's a great tip. Hope I could give you many points for this fabulous answer.

Comment: Glad that it helps :). Entity Framework is getting quite confusing with all the different options.

The generated fluent API to map the classes to tables is quite redundant, since Code First Convention does the exact same mapping already. Odd thing is that TableAttribute **should** work in the absence of the fluent API mapping `Order_Details`, but it didn't in ur case

Comment: Yes, I agree EF is getting more confusing. ADO.Net is so clean and straightforward compared to EF.